# How can I find out the time required to perform of a particular instruction for Xtensa microprocessor for e.g. wsr / rsr?

Tags: performance, assembly, micro-optimization, esp32, xtensa

I am trying to optimize a code on esp32 which uses xtensa LX6 microprocessors , I wanted to know the cost of wsr and rsr instructions which are used to read or wirte in the special registers .

Comment: after wchich I can decide whether using rsr and wsr is costly or not !!

Comment: Have you read the reference manual?

Comment: You need to measure and identify the bottleneck before anything else. First **write code that is simple to understand**. Then measure, then write convoluted code and measure. Then keep the "easy" code regardless.

Answer (score 1):

Our first step should be the [Xtensa ISA reference manual](https://www.cadence.com/content/dam/cadence-www/global/en_US/documents/tools/ip/tensilica-ip/isa-summary.pdf#page=70&zoom=100,0,69). Cycle timings aren't always available for Xtensa-derived cores, but we can find some useful information in section "3.8.10 Processor Control Instructions", which explains what these instructions including RSR and WSR do, and when they take effect. There are a few important facts to consider:

1. When updating special registers with WSR, the time at which the write takes effect can depend on the selected register, and is often guaranteed until the appropriate SYNC instruction following WSR completes.
2. There's a cycle count register, CCOUNT, shown in Table 21 - this means we should be able to use the processor to measure itself, rather than using a GPIO or other means(which may involve crossbar or IOMUX contention).
3. RSR may have more than one cycle of latency, so to avoid measurement errors, we should avoid using the resulting general purpose register immediately when benchmarking.
4. General unrelated note: we should place our benchmarking code in internal SRAM, so that we don't have to worry about QSPI fetch latency, though you could also run it repeatedly and take the minimum.

Since you're using ESP32, you can use the [XTHAL_GET_CCOUNT()](https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/blob/master/components/xtensa/include/xtensa/core-macros.h#L353C10-L353C26) and related macros. I'll run the code samples below through GCC12 with -Og and run them on an ESP32-S3.

This first one runs RSR twice to get a measurement baseline to see how long RSR takes, and the below function returns a cycle count difference of 1:

```
uint32_t IRAM_ATTR meas0(void)
{
uint32_t before = XTHAL_GET_CCOUNT();
uint32_t after = XTHAL_GET_CCOUNT();
return after - before;
}

//compiles to:
meas0():
    entry   sp, 32
    rsr.ccount a8 ;caveat - using a8 in the next instruction may stall
    rsr.ccount a2
    sub     a2, a2, a8 ;but we don't use a8 until here
    retw.n
```

Here's using RSR.ccount to measure WSR, but without waiting for it take effect, and returns a difference of 2 cycles:

```
uint32_t meas1(uint32_t n)
{
uint32_t start = XTHAL_GET_CCOUNT();
_XTHAL_SET_CCOMPARE(0,n);
return XTHAL_GET_CCOUNT() - start;
}

//compiles to:
meas1(unsigned long):
    entry   sp, 32
    rsr.ccount a8
    wsr.ccompare0 a2 ; esync
    rsr.ccount a2
    sub     a2, a2, a8
    retw.n
```

How expensive could it be though? Here's a single ISYNC to block fetching future instructions while some previous things finish. This function returns 9 cycles:

```
uint32_t meas2(uint32_t n)
{
uint32_t start = XTHAL_GET_CCOUNT();
_XTHAL_SET_CCOMPARE(0,n);
xthal_icache_sync();
return XTHAL_GET_CCOUNT() - start;
}

//compiles to:
meas2(unsigned long):
    entry   sp, 32
    rsr.ccount a8
    wsr.ccompare0 a2
    isync
    rsr.ccount a2
    sub     a2, a2, a8
    retw.n
```

There's also a larger barrier sequence DHWB/MEMW/IHI/ISYNC needed for JIT, but that's fairly rare and I didn't think to try it out.

Xtensa is an especially vague architecture, given that Cadence doesn't always entirely design the core, rather they design and sell the tools to design the core, which is often done by the SoC vendor or another party. The Xtensa LX6 has either a 5 or 7 stage pipeline, and I haven't found where Espressif specifies what their specific core does, but I'd guess it's 7 stage, due to the ISYNC taking 7 additional cycles past the WSR.

Generally, you may be better off profiling a larger block of instructions using CCOUNT though, to avoid worrying too much about the finer pipeline effects impacting your measurements.

There is also an example 5-stage pipeline capable of issuing no more than 1 IPC documented in the older 2010 ISA reference manual, but the 2022 ISA reference manual now states "Because the instruction execution pipeline is implementation-specific..." in a bunch of places instead.

Answer (score -1):

First of all, optimize only after you have profiled, and came to the conclusion that this is your bottleneck.

In rare cases (like a function that accesses registers) it might be a good idea to optimize code generated by the compiler, but usually, that is not where the bottleneck is.

In general, when optimizing compiler-generated code:

1. write a very simple function (that produces the asm you think you can optimize)
2. **create TESTS for this function (people tend to introduce weird bugs when writing their own asm)**
3. run & measure
4. replace the generated asm with your optimizations
5. **test you haven't screwed up the logic**
6. run & measure again

Even if you managed to optimize, think about readability, portability, maintenance, etc. before choosing your optimized version.